# Moving individual team sites to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, migration

We are looking to migrate our 2010 Environment to a 2013 and wanted to test the process for upgrading with a sample team site to start. Is there an easy way to migrate ONLY one of many team sites from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to 2013?

**EDIT:**

I am looking to be able to move 1 Team Site, with a url of say

`http://sharepoint.com/TeamSite`

The reason for this is that all the sites were configured under the Central Admin Site (not me, people before me), which obviously is a bad configuration. Because of this, all the content for these sites is in the AdminContent DB. Is there an easy way to just take a subsite and map it, or do you need to bring the whole collection?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a site collection, the easiest way would be to move it into it's own database using the `Move-SPSite` and then upgrade that database.

If you do not want to impact production database arrangement you can restore a backup to test/dev 2010 farm and perform the move there and then upgrade the database to 2013.

Keep in mind that the default auth method has changed from classic in 2010 to claims in 2013